# Stored Procedure Select Statement in While Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

I want to execute my select query in While loop but it doesn't work.

```
Set @i = 1
    While(@i <= @rowNumber) 

    BEGIN

       Set @q_getoldeMail =  'SELECT Lower('+@columnname+') FROM (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rownumber
          ,ID
          ,[Name]
          ,[Description]
          ,[Status]
          ,[AssignedTo]
          ,[AssignedToMail]
          ,[CC]
      FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ') AS ar Where rownumber = '+@i+''

    exec sp_executesql @q_getoldeMail, N'@get_oldeMail nvarchar(100) output', @get_oldeMail output

      Set @i = @i+1
```

In other respects, I tried execute query without while loop like this:

```
Set @q_getoldeMail =  'SELECT Lower('+@columnname+') FROM (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rownumber
              ,ID
              ,[Name]
              ,[Description]
              ,[Status]
              ,[AssignedTo]
              ,[AssignedToMail]
              ,[CC]
          FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename) + ') AS ar Where rownumber = '+@i+''

        exec sp_executesql @q_getoldeMail, N'@get_oldeMail nvarchar(100) output', @get_oldeMail output
```

It doesn't work, either. What is my mistake? Is there a way get a value from `Select` statement with While loop? Can you help me?

EDIT:

I set the @rowcount value in this code part:

```
SET @q_getrowNumber = 'SELECT Count(ID)
FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tablename) + ''

execute sp_executesql @q_getrowNumber, N'@rownumber int output', @rownumber output
```

This code part returns a value (112). But when I change @rowcount

```
Set @rowcount = 2
```

then the code works. I tried convert to integer @rowcount but it didn't work

Comment: "it doesn't work." Please explain. What sort of behavior or error message do you get?

Comment: What does it mean - "DOESN'T WORK". ???

Comment: The Mistake is in While loop Here While (i <= rowNumber)  When you are try to increment @i Value Set i = i+1 It will go in a loop and check if  still i <= rowNumber  And I think loop is not getting rownumber

Comment: You've only posted half your code and you haven't explained "doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for  -

```
declare @i int = 1
declare @rownumber int = 2
declare @result_set table (value varchar(1000))
declare @q_getoldeMail nvarchar(max)
declare @columnname varchar(100) = 'name'
declare @tablename varchar(100) = 'sys.columns'
--select * from sys.columns

Set @i = 1
While(@i <= @rowNumber)
BEGIN
    Set @q_getoldeMail = 'SELECT Lower('+@columnname+') FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_ID) AS rownumber
        ,object_id
        ,name
    FROM ' + (@tablename) + ') AS ar Where rownumber = '+convert(varchar,@i)+''

    insert into @result_set
    exec sp_executesql @q_getoldeMail

    Set @i = @i+1
end

select * from @result_set
```

Comment: how will I max rownum from table